# What are the paid features of Play Framework - 2

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, reactive-programming

I am exploring Play Framework 2 for our new project that needs:

1. Highly concurrent Non-blocking IO on Sockets
2. Highly scalable
3. Learning curve is easy
4. Deployment is hassle free
5. Automation in testing is available

My questions are:

1. I want to understand is Play the right choice & what are the features that are only available/supported in **Paid version** ?
2. I have read that the **Reactive** support is only available in paid subscription, is it really true?
3. I am a **Java** guy, so how good is the development and maintenance in Play as compared to Java?

Answer (score 2):

- There are no paid features in play. All functionality is available for everybody.
- You pay for support only. Meaning, you can contact the company behind Play for help/support if needed.
- Last, Play is a scala first framework with an API for Java. That implies, it will be easier, faster, better in Scala. However, all functionality is available in Java.

Comment: Thanks Mic, but the question was intended to connect to people using Play and get their opinion on technology perspective rather than an opinion to decide whether use play or not.

Comment: Then you are on the wrong website.